# Windows phone background transfer service is not working with the redirect urls with status 302

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, background-thread

In my windows phone application, i want to download zip file from the server. I used `Background Transfer Service` for downloading file. And it works for me for some service urls.

But now i tried with downloading file from a url, [Actually on hitting it is redirected to another url] for downloading the actual data.

By using Http Web Request method, i am able to download the data, but on using background transfer service it's status is always on a waiting stage .

```
    public AddBackgroundTransfer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var url= "www.firsturl.com";

        using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (!isoStore.DirectoryExists("/shared/transfers"))
            {
                isoStore.CreateDirectory("/shared/transfers");
            }
        }

    BackgroundTransferRequest transferRequest = new BackgroundTransferRequest(transferUri);
    transferRequest.Method = "GET";

    //adding headers
    Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        headers.Add("APPKEY", "somekey");            

        if (headers != null)
        {
            foreach (var key in headers.Keys)
            {
                transferRequest.Headers.Add(key, headers[key]);
            }
        }

        Uri downloadUri = new Uri("shared/transfers/" + "myfile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        transferRequest.DownloadLocation = downloadUri;

        try
        {
            BackgroundTransferService.Add(transferRequest);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to add background transfer request. " + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to add background transfer request.");
        }

    }

    private void ProcessTransfer(BackgroundTransferRequest transfer)
    {
        switch (transfer.TransferStatus)
        {
          //case

        }
    }
```

Here am getting Status as Waiting and BytesToRecieve Value is always -1. And the redirection status seems 302.

And i tried this with Fiddler, there it is redirected in to another url and downloading starts.

Do i need to set any value value to correct it? Please provide me any suggestion.

Comment: Suggestion: post some code. :-) Also, are you testing this in the emulator, or do you only see this behaviour on a device? Also: what kind of redirect is happening on the target Url?

Comment: @DanPuzey Hi i updated answer. But sorry for not revealing the exact download url since it is confidential. The urls which is not redirecting is working fine with the background transfer .

Comment: Can you answer the second question? How is the redirect being handled? (Is it a 301 or 302 status, or other?)

Comment: @DanPuzey I s there any problem in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background downloader wont download the redirect urls. you need to check with the server whether the download url is available one or not

Comment: is there anyway to get the redirect url from the original url ?  so i can pass it to the background download .